# Outlook Rules - Alternative to wildcards

Tags: vba, outlook

Every day I get one or more spam emails of a very specific type to my xxxxx@gmail account.

They all have a garbled and unique FROM: email address.

The TO: and CC: fields are always of the form xxxxx[random chars]@aol.com. For example I got one today with

TO: xxxxx@aol.com
CC: xxxxxY7@aol.com

I would like to create a rule to automatically send these to spam and block. Two possible conditionals would be:

1. "with xxxxx AND @aol.com in recipient's address"
2. "with xxxxx*@aol.com in recipient's address" (with * as a wildcard).

#1 doesnt work because the "specific words" it requests are concatenated with OR, no option to use AND.

#2 doesn't work because as far as I can tell there is no way to use wildcards.

Any suggestions? I realize there probably is a straightforward VBA script solution but I haven't played with VBA in over a decade. Was hoping there might be another clever non-VBA work around. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no workaround. You can handle incoming emails in Outlook VBA by handling the [NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex) event of the `Application` class. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. You can use the Entry ID from the `EntryIDCollection` parameter to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

In the `NewMailEx` event handler you can check the required properties such as `Recipients` and etc. and move the item wherever you need.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was about to roll up my sleeves and use your advice to write a VBA script when I realized that there is a straightforward solution to my problem (not wildcards or AND conditions generally).

I just created a rule that sends any email with "xxxxx" in recipient address to spam folder EXCEPT with "xxxxxx@gmail.com" (my actual email address) in the recipient address. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, NewMailEx can be used to handle some filtering like this and I have a regex filter that I use as standard automatic rules don't allow that (or at least not currently - maybe a future upgrade). If you can use a regex to identify the e-mails you want to process then you could use this code:

> In ThisOutlookSession

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    Call RegExFilterRules(EntryIDCollection)
End Sub
```

> In a module

```
Sub RegExFilterRules(ItemID As String)
    With Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder: Set Inbox = .GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
        Dim Junk As Outlook.MAPIFolder: Set Junk = .GetDefaultFolder(olFolderJunk)
        Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem: Set olItem = .GetItemFromID(ItemID, Inbox.StoreID)
    End With

    'On Error Resume Next
    If Not olItem Is Nothing And olItem.Class = olMail Then
        If IsPatternFound(olItem.subject, "^M\d+$") Then olItem.Move Junk 'olItem.Delete 'olItem.UnRead = False
        If olItem.Sender = "cortana@microsoft.com" Then olItem.Delete
    End If
    Set olItem = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function IsPatternFound(Content As String, Pattern As String) As Boolean
    ' Requires Reference: Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim RegEx As Object: Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.RegExp")
    With RegEx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = Pattern
        IsPatternFound = .Test(Content)
    End With
End Function
```