# Outlook rule run in all the folders

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a VBA script that is running a rule in outlook repeating the rule execution every 10 minutes.
Is working like a charm, but I have a small problem, the rule is working just in the Inbox folder, and I need to work on all the folders.
I tried with "IncludeSubfolders:=True" without luck.
Here is my script:

```
Public Sub TriggerTimer(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal idevent As Long, ByVal Systime As Long)
Dim oOk As Outlook.Application

Set oOk = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then Set oOk = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

oOk.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules.Item("AssistantPlanifRobot").Execute

MsgBox "Rule run"
End Sub
```

and the timer part:

```
Public Sub ActivateTimer(ByVal nMinutes As Long)
  nMinutes = nMinutes * 1000 * 60 'milliseconds
  If TimerID <> 0 Then Call DeactivateTimer 'Check to see if timer is running before call to SetTimer
  TimerID = SetTimer(0, 0, nMinutes, AddressOf TriggerTimer)
  If TimerID = 0 Then
    MsgBox "The timer failed to activate."
  End If
End Sub
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: As this is calling a rule in the session, I would first look to see if the rule itself can be altered to run across all folders. If that isn't possible you will need a full VBA solution so rather than call the rule, you could [iterate all subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69403087/3688861) then process each folder in turn within VBA. Otherwise you may need to process e-mails as they arrive instead of using a timer with the [NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex) event such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70458174/3688861)

Comment: Are **all the folders you want the rule working** subfolders of `Inbox`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above, the default behavior of running rules is to be run in `Inbox`.

But you can run a specific rule on a specific folder.  I manually moved some mails making the rule object, in a specific folder and run the next code, which works:

```
Sub testDefaultStore()
   Dim oRules As Outlook.Rules, rul As Outlook.Rule, ruleName As String
   Dim objNS As NameSpace, ctrlBr As Outlook.Folder, folderName As String
   
   ruleName = "the real rule name" 
   folderName ="the folder name where to run"' 
   Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
   Set ctrlBr = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(folderName)
   
   Set oRules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules
   For Each rul In oRules
        Debug.Print rul.RuleType, rul.Name
        If rul.Name = ruleName Then
            rul.Execute ShowProgress:=True, Folder:=ctrlBr
        End If
   Next
End Sub
```

It is just an example of running on a specific folder.

Knowing the rule name and folder name, you can directly try:

```
oOk.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules.Item("AssistantPlanifRobot").Execute ShowProgress:=True, Folder:=ctrlBr
```

The used folder should be set as above. Even if it is not an `Inbox` subfolder, I can show you how, but now I must leave my office.

For `Inbox` and its subfolders, it should work as:

```
oOk.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules.Item("AssistantPlanifRobot").Execute ShowProgress:=True,IncludeSubfolders:=True
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, rules are run against the Inbox folder in Outlook.

Instead of relying on the rules in Outlook (end-user things) you can do everything in the code, so consider implementing the required functionality in VBA without rules involved.